# Missing data in X and Y: How Do I get the X and Y from the actual estimated model?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am estimating a logit model to perform roc and auroc analyses.
My dataset includes nan both in X and Y. When I estimated the model, the fitted y obtained using res.predict() is, therefore, shorter. 
I need to recover the actual y used in the logit-estimation to compare it with the fitted values. Is it possible? Do you know how?

Comment: Hi please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question. Without the code that you already tried it is basically making your homework and will not help you understand it. Post your code in such a way that it is quick to understand and without unnecessary code so we can point out what went wrong and help you out.

Comment: Dear Uber, thank you for the advice. There is no code to show and I do not need any homework. I just ask if there is such a function in statsmodels. Is it possible to get the actual X and Y used in the estimation when there are missing numbers?